# Looping through input with hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML form that I need to perform a loop through using jQuery to check whether each element has a `required` class attached to it.

Here's my HTML layout:

```
<form>
    <p class="form-field  first_name pd-text required">
        First Name<br>
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
    </p>
    <p class="form-field  last_name pd-text required">
        Last Name<br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
    </p>
    <p class="form-field  mobile pd-text required">
        Mobile<br>
        <input type="text" name="mobile">
    </p>
    <p class="form-field  email pd-text">
        Email<br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </p>
    <p class="form-field  skype pd-text">
        Skype<br>
        <input type="text" name="skype">
    </p>
</form>
```

As you can see only some of the `p` elements have a `required` class attached, I need to do some kind of `foreach` loop and append an asterisk sign after the text, so for example:

```
    <p class="form-field  first_name pd-text required">
        First Name
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
    </p>
```

Would become

```
    <p class="form-field  first_name pd-text required">
        First Name *
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
    </p>
```

Is this possible inside jQuery?

Comment: _Possible?_, Of course, `$('.required').each(function() {`

Comment: If you changed your html to use labels for the labelling this could be done even by pure css

Comment: ⇑⇑⇑ See e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/d7okLpxe/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  can use :

```
$('.required').each(function() {
  $(this).contents()[0].textContent += ' *';
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gL1uwf87/)**

Comment: Pretty similar to what I did in the end, but thanks for your time anyway and I've accepted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this using the following :

```
$('.required').each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(index, currentHtml) {
        return currentHtml.replace('<br>', '*<br>');
    });
});
```